# Bug in boost::math:quadrature::sinh_sinh?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013

I was searching for a library for numeric quadrature on the whole real line, i.e. (-inf,inf), and I found boost (version 1.70.0). The function I want to use is boost::math::quadrature:sinh_sinh. To test it I copied the example code from the documentation:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/double_exponential/de_sinh_sinh.html

and came up with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/quadrature/sinh_sinh.hpp>

using namespace boost::math::quadrature;

int main()
{
    sinh_sinh<double> integrator;
    auto f = [](double x) { return exp(-x*x); };
    double error;
    double L1;
    double Q = integrator.integrate(f, &error, &L1);
    std::cout << Q << "\t" << error << "\t" << L1 << std::endl;

    int i = 0;
    std::cin >> i; // Just to make sure the console does not close automatically
}
```

Unfortunately this would not compile because in the documentation the second argument for "integrate" is not a pointer to a Real number, but a normal Real number. So I had to change this line:

```
double Q = integrator.integrate(f, &error, &L1);
```

into this one:

```
double Q = integrator.integrate(f , boost::math::tools::root_epsilon<double>() , &error, &L1);
```

This compiled and gave good results. But I was curious if I could just write

```
double Q = integrator.integrate(f);
```

because all arugments except the first one have default values (and are hence optional to my understanding of c++). Unfortunately this will not compile with Visual-Studio-2013. The error is:

error C2783: "T boost::math::tools::root_epsilon(void)": template-Argument für "T" konnte nicht hergeleitet werden. (in english: it was not able to derive the template-argument for "T" )

Occuring at line 33 of pathTo\boost_1_70_0\boost\math\quadrature\sinh_sinh.hpp

As I am not sure if this error is only related to Visual-Studio I wanted to ask all of you.

Now I wanted to use the working code on my function of interest, which is:

```
auto f = [](double x) {return pow(abs(x), 3) / cosh(x); };
```

This function looks like this:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs(x)%5E3%2Fcosh(x)

and the result of the quadrature should be approx. 23.7:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+abs(x)%5E3%2Fcosh(x)+from+-+inf+to+inf

This program compiles with this function but it crashes, i.e. I get the "The program has stopped working" message from Windows. When I compile in debug mode and run it I get the following error message:

[image]

So my question is basically why boost::math::quadrature::sinh_sinh is not able to integrate this function. It decays to zero for plus and minus infinity and it has no singularities.

Is it possible that all these errors occur because I am using Visual-Studio?

Comment: Try `auto f = [](double x)->double { ... };`. I think Visual Studio 2013 can handle that. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Visual studio is not being nice to you. On your second example, I get the more intelligible error message:

```cpp
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::math::evaluation_error>'
  what():  Error in function boost::math::quadrature::sinh_sinh<double>::integrate: The sinh_sinh quadrature evaluated your function at a singular point, leading to the value nan.
sinh_sinh quadrature cannot handle singularities in the domain.
If you are sure your function has no singularities, please submit a bug against boost.math
```

I added a bit of diagnostic code to help out:

```cpp
auto f = [](double x) {
    double y = pow(abs(x), 3) / cosh(x);
    if (!std::isfinite(y)) {
        std::cout << "f(" << x << ") = " << y << "\n";
    }
    return y;
};
```

I get:

```sh
f(1.79769e+308) = nan
f(-1.79769e+308) = nan
f(2.01977e+137) = nan
f(-2.01977e+137) = nan
f(7.35294e+106) = nan
f(-7.35294e+106) = nan
```

Most people are very surprised to learn that sinh-sinh quadrature evaluates their function at such huge argument. It also forces them to think about things they don't usually have to, namely:

*IEEE arithmetic can't take limits.*

For example, you might know that as $x \to \infty$, $x^2/(1+x^4) \to 0$. But in IEEE floating point arithmetic, for sufficiently large $x$, both the numerator and denominator overflow, and what can be done? The only sensible solution is to just make inf/inf a nan.

In your case, *you* know that `cosh(x)` grows faster than `pow(|x|, 3)`, but IEEE doesn't. So you need to explicitly tell the function about the limiting behavior as $x->\infty$ via:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/math/quadrature/sinh_sinh.hpp>

using namespace boost::math::quadrature;

int main()
{
    sinh_sinh<double> integrator;
    auto f = [](double x) {
        double numerator = pow(abs(x), 3);
        if (!std::isfinite(numerator)) { 
            return double(0);
        }
        return numerator / cosh(x);
    };
    double error;
    double L1;
    double tolerance = std::sqrt(std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon());
    double Q = integrator.integrate(f, tolerance, &error, &L1);
    std::cout << Q << "\t" << error << "\t" << L1 << std::endl;
}
```

One final comment: Your integrand is even, so you can use `exp_sinh` quadrature over `[0, inf]` and double the result.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Can you tell me what the difference between the tolerance variable you are using and the one I was using is? And yeah in this case I could also use the exp_sinh quadrature. But this was just a minimal example to reproduce my error. In what I really want to do the integrand will not be even any more. One more question if it is allowed. Do you know how to change my code to use multiprecision numbers? I tried changing all occurances of "double" to boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_quad. But VS tells me that there is no template for sinh_sinh for this type.

Comment: There is no difference between the two tolerances. The one you use is just known at compile-time, which allows it to be used as a default argument.

Comment: Post a separate question for the cpp_bin_float_quad. Other people have hit that issue as well so I'd like to give a focused answer that will come up in search results.